# Little issue with div sticking to top of the page

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/j2qjgob5/

```
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="new_country">
      <div id="new_country_text" >
       New Country
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div id="space"><br><br>blablablablabballabla</div>

#container {
padding: 100px 0 2500px;
}

#wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 57px;
   border: solid;
}

#new_country {
  width: 162px;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 8px;
}

#new_country:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#new_country:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 4px #16a085 inset;
}

#new_country_text {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    display: table;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#wrapper");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) {
        $('#wrapper').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '0',
                'width': '100%'
        });
    } else {
        $('#wrapper').css({
            'position': 'static',
                'top': 'auto',
                'width': '100%'
        });
    }
}

$("#wrapper").data("top", $("#wrapper").offset().top); // set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

Every time the wrapper div sticks to the top, div below it kind of spazzes upwards and then the wrapper div twitches. How do I get the div to stick to the top smoothly, without affecting any other divs? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one you need to clear the default margin from the document:

```
html,body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Your JS is changing the width and height on `.wrapper` to:

```
$('#wrapper').css({'position': 'static', 'width': '100%', 'height': '57px', })
```

But your CSS for `.wrapper` on page load is:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 50%;
   height: 44px;
   ...
}
```

Make them the same:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   height: 57px;
   ...
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2qjgob5/1/)

**UPDATE 2**

So the issue is the `.wrapper` becomes `fixed` which removes it from the flow of the document and that causes the `#space` section to just jump to the top of the page (because the header is no longer being recognized). A simpler way of doing all of this is to just add/remove a class like so:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
    $('#wrapper').addClass("fixed"); 
}
else {
    $('#wrapper').removeClass("fixed"); 
}
```

and then in your CSS you can add your rules and also adjust the padding of `#space` since it's a sibling:

```css
.fixed{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   //any other styles
}

.fixed + #space{ //target sibling #space
   padding: 57px 0 0; //set padding to height of .wrapper
}
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j2qjgob5/6/)

Comment: This is the problem. The static position pays attention to the default margin but fixed doesn't, so when it switches over, you see that change.

Comment: Thanks. That made the wrapper div stick well to the top. However, the space div below doesn't seem to smoothly go underneath it. Like when the wrapper div sticks to the top, the blablabla text abruptly disappears.

Comment: Shoot sorry. I still need the top bar to be able to move around the screen. Edited: http://jsfiddle.net/j2qjgob5/5/
So, the blablabla text isn't very smooth.

Comment: @StephanieKim ahhh i get it. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank it works great! Also, thanks for replying so quickly :)